# Does Bender have a heart under that metal chest?

Tags: futurama

Does Bender have a conscience? Or, is he always that bad? Is he bad because he does not have a conscience?

Answer (score 2):

In the episode where Fry thinks he is a robot, at the end of the episode Bender says "just like inside me I have the heart of a human".

Answer (score 0):

Bender is a robot, who runs on alcohol and artificial intelligence. He has no organs whatsoever (If he did then his liver would fail because of all the alcohol andhe would die.) Because he has no organs or muscles then he obviously has no heart. Also, even speaking metaphorically, have you heard Bender speak? He laughs at pain, flushes pets down the toilet etc... The chance of him having a heart, is el zilcho.

Comment: I should point out there are rare moments (emphasis on rare) moments when Bender "does the right thing" (one example: refuses to execute Leela and Fry in Fear of a Bot Planet).

Answer (score 0):

He does have an actual human heart in his chest compartment, but before he met Fry he used to follow his program.  He was electrocuted at the head museum and that allowed him to do what he wanted.  Technically Bender has been bad since the beginning of time but that was because of time travel.

Answer (score 0):

No he doesn't, because otherwise he would not have needed to see the Wizard to get one so as he could pump a lot of blood out of his basement.